# Is there a way to find out max Memory per slot

Tags: laptop, memory, motherboard

I have a Packard Bell EasyNote Packard Bell (a division of Acer) Easynote TE69BM (ENTE69BM-29204G50Mnsk) laptop which has 4gb of memory stock. All PC scans show that there are two RAM slots, but when the laptop is opened, there are two slots but only one of them has the memory holder/mount. All system scanners report that there is a maximum of 8gb allowed. After inserting an 8gb stick of RAM, the laptop does not boot. Here are my questions:

- Is there any way to find out the maximum memory allowed in each slot (the manufacturers website doesn't say)?
- Is it possible to solder in an extra RAM slot/holder (probably not)?

The missing ram holder on the left
[image: showing missing RAM socket]

EDIT: I believe the laptop wouldn't boot due to the memory being 1600 insted of the max supported by the CPU (1066)

Comment: That would be a terrible idea to solder in an extra RAM slot / holder.. It would not work.

Comment: Interesting, crucial says it supports up to 8 in a 2x4 configuration...  But you have only one mount...  I *strongly* suspect you dont have the model you think you do.

Comment: Despite the fact the [Celeron N2920](http://ark.intel.com/products/79053/Intel-Celeron-Processor-N2920-2M-Cache-up-to-2_00-GHz) supports up to 8GB of memory the configuration of your motherboard does not.  To put it in simple terms, you do not have the ability to use 8Gb of memory on this device, its not possible.  **There likely is a similar model that does support it but you don't have it.**

Comment: *"only one of them has the memory holder/mount."* -- The proper/correct term is a **socket** or **connector**.  Every slot is a socket, but not every socket is a slot, contrary to common (mis)usage.

Comment: insert 2 4GB modules and NOT 1 8GB one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory you inserted maybe too fast/slow, sometimes there is a brand compatibility issue (although very rare these days)

In some laptops the other memory slot is under the keyboard, so they put memory in there at the factory and when you open the bottom cover, there is no ram installed (freaked me out the first time I saw it).

It seems like in your case the two slots are "present" at the bottom, but only one physically installed.

Now, if that is the case, it should be possible to solder a new slot, but if you don't feel competent doing this yourself, just have a friend (or pay someone) to do it. There is a hole wackload of things that can go wrong. Keep in mind that not every laptop repair shop will even attempt this, and if they do, it will probably cost you half the laptop.

To discourage you from soldering, consider this:

- First you have to get the slot that is designed for the pads on your MB - the logic pads are expected to be the same, but the mounting ones have to be located exactly in the same place as the MB has them (and every manufacturer is free to change this to their likes).
- When soldering, care must be taken not to overheat the board as you only see the top and bottom layers of the MB, but there may be a few more in between, overheat one and the entire MB is a toast.

If you bought the laptop new and can still return it, I would do that (or find one with the second slot in place).
If not, try to find your MB on eBay and then sell yours.
To do this, you'll need to crack your laptop open and take a picture of the motherboard and all the connectors.
Every now and then, the same laptop model may have a slightly different port configuration (an extra USB port, or a firewire, or something).
Rarely, the MB will look different (this will usually be compliant with the laptop revision). Say you got a second generation model of the laptop: to you it will look "the same", but the MB may be completely different and not fit from one rev to the other.

I replaced a MB before where the new MB did not have a firewire port on it (luckily the owner of the laptop was a senior man and didn't use digital video cameras or any other gadgets that required it, so he didn't care). So he just had a "hole" where his old firewire port was...

Comment: I can't return the laptop because there are no official specs which say that there are two memory slots, or up to 8gb max memory!

Comment: @adamantium - So its safe to assume the memory limits are below 8GB since you cannot find any documentation that says otherwise.  You can look at the supported chipsets the CPU supports to determine that maximum amount of memory it can supports.  Just because the CPU supports 8GB doesn't mean the system will boot if the chipset implement on the motherboard only supports 4GB.

Comment: I'm putting a -1 on this because I don't believe there is any human who could solder that, so even offering the half-hope is too much. As the joints/holes [if any] are already flowed, you would need to heat all at once to be able to attach the new component. If they were still raw, there would be little chance; ready flowed there is zero.

Comment: Actually, I would very happily do this for OP. The only problem is getting the right part and shipping it to/from me. Since OP does not know me, I doubt this will happen, but I have the equipment and am willing to do this absolutely free of charge (except shipping). I don't believe my answer deserved a downvote...

Comment: @Tetsujin This wouldn't be too difficult with the right tools, I could probably get it right with a half decent heat gun or infra-red heater and some solder paste.  Doing it cleanly with conventional solder and a soldering iron would be difficult though.  It's not impossible to do by any means though.

Comment: @Mokubai & nurchi - fair point, I really meant it's not a job for an amateur with a soldering iron. Most people don't have that kind of facility at home. Unfortunately, I don't appear have the rep yet to reverse my vote unless there's an edit.

Comment: Chosen as best answer

Answer (score 2):

I would say your chances of being able to add the other RAM mount at home would be just slightly less than those of the proverbial snowball in hell.

Don't even think of it.

Computer PCBs are not soldered by hand… ever.

Comment: [also see my comment on the other answer] I really did mean for the amateur with a soldering iron, not those who already own the right tools.